# Basic SQL. Is there a better way to use aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table 'Country' (the one which comes as a demo with the SQLWorkbench) with attributes : 'name' and 'IndepYear'.

I want to find the year with more countries becoming independent, I'm not interested in their names.

This query works.

```
SELECT Nest.IndepYear, Nest.conta 
  FROM (Select IndepYear,count(IndepYear) AS conta 
   FROM country  GROUP BY IndepYear) Nest 
    WHERE Nest.conta = (Select max(conta) FROM (SELECT IndepYear,count(IndepYear) AS conta 
     FROM country GROUP BY IndepYear)Nest2)
```

Output

```
IndepYear   Conta
1960        18
1991        18
```

Is there a smarter, more readable or more efficent way to do this?

EDIT : Thanks for the answers so far but I was interested in getting **only** the top *results*. I mean getting all the first n rows and those rows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far from perfect, but may give you some ideas on how to improve your query:

```
select IndepYear, count(*) 
from country 
group by IndepYear 
having count(*) = (
  select count(*) from country group by IndepYear order by count(*) desc limit 1
)
```

Comment: Yep it works.Thanks. In case anyone using the same demo database from mySQLWorkbench wants to try this use `count(IndepYear)` not `count(*)` since there are many NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following SQL should do the trick:

```
SELECT IndepYear, count(IndepYear) conta
FROM Countries
GROUP BY IndepYear
ORDER By count(IndepYear) DESC
```

Please refer to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0a37/4) for complete solution.